# Checking that all property values of array objects are the same in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an object

```
var checkerObject = {
    'Id': '',
    'Tracked':''
}

var checkerObjects = [];
```

and based on certain actions I do on a page I set Tracked to 1 and then add the object to a collection of these objects.

```
checkerObjects.push(checkerObject);
```

The amount of objects may vary. Is there a quick way to check that all the *Tracked* values in the array are set to 1?

Something like

```
if(checkerObjects.Where(t=>t.Tracked==0).Count()==0)
{
     //all the tracked values are 1
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```
var everyoneIsTracked = checkerObjects.every(function (obj) { 
    return obj.Tracked == 1;
});

if (everyoneIsTracked) {
    // stuff
}
```